# Problem deploying function to Cloud Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a simple function do Cloud Firestore. This function will patch the data. But whenever I attempt to deploy I get an error:

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    webApi
```

This is the code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as firebaseHelper from 'firebase-functions-helper/dist';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

const app = express();
const main = express();

main.use(bodyParser.json());
main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
main.use('/api/v1', app);

const sensorsCollection = 'dadosusuarios';
export const webApi = functions.https.onRequest(main);

app.patch('/Name/:sensorId', async(req, res) => {
    try{
        await firebaseHelper.firestoreHelper.updateDocument(db, sensorsCollection, req.params.sensorId, req.body);
        res.status(200).send('Update Success');
    }catch(error){
        res.status(204).send('Patch Error');
    }
})
```

Database image:
[image]

This is the error log I got from debbuging the code:

```
{
textPayload: "ERROR"
insertId: "da-das-47d7-925a-da-29"
resource: {2}
timestamp: "2021-01-27T01:39:05.703003866Z"
severity: "INFO"
labels: {1}
logName: "projects/automacao-com-aplicativo/logs/cloudbuild"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-01-27T01:39:05.952913755Z"
}

textPayload: "ERROR: error fetching storage source: generic::unknown: retry budget exhausted (3 attempts): fetching gcs source: unpacking source from gcs: source fetch container exited with non-zero status: 1"
insertId: "a528e7ab-dsa-47d7-dsa-9bcc6b5624bb-30"
resource: {2}
timestamp: "2021-01-27T01:39:05.703023756Z"
severity: "INFO"
labels: {1}
logName: "projects/automacao-com-aplicativo/logs/cloudbuild"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-01-27T01:39:05.952913755Z"
}
```

Comment: Can you try deploying with `firebase deploy --only functions:webApi --debug` and share the content of the firebase-debug.log file that will be in your project's root directory after the deployment with the --debug flag set? It will have more information about the error.

Comment: This is what I Got from the debug: `[warn] ⚠  functions[webApi(us-central1)]: Deployment error. 
[info] Build failed: Build error details not available. Please check the logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=automacao-com-aplicativo&advancedFilter=resource.type%3Dbuild%0Aresource.labels.build_id%3Da528e7ab-9e94-47d7-925a-9bcc6b5624bb%0AlogName%3Dprojects%2Fautomacao-com-aplicativo%2Flogs%2Fcloudbuild
[info] `

Comment: @hemauricio I noticed that my project is at us-west2, and it is deploying at us-cenrtal1, does that influences in something

Comment: No, that's only the default Cloud Functions location; You can deploy multiple functions in different locations. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations.

If you go to the link in the warning, what are the logs saying?

Comment: I have made an edit with the errors I got

Comment: I have attempted to use JavaScript but it just doesn't gives me error message

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with the same error message.

Are you deploying from your computer? If so, make sure you are using **Node 12** when you deploy.

To check your current Node version, you can use `node --version`. If you need multiple Node versions (for different projects), I would suggest using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). Otherwise, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65955925/8164939) to a similar question to downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to take in consideration:

- make sure that you have the latest `firebase-tools` you can install the latest version with `npm install -g firebase-tools`
- make sure that you are using the correct account. use `firebase login`. your account should have at least the role `Cloud Functions Deployer`
- initialize the correct project with `firebase init`
- check if you have billing enabled for your project. You cannot deploy functions with spark plan
- check if you have any linting issues like unused variables
- deploy your functions with `firebase deploy --only functions`
- sometimes a deployment may fail for no reason and you just need to try again

Comment: I have made all of those steps correct, I just don't get why it isn't working

Comment: How are you deploying your functions? with the cli or from the console and what command are you running. what firebase tools do you have? can you try to deploy a simple function like the one that comes with the `firebase init`? it should a simple hello world function

Comment: I'm deploying from the console, and I'm running firebase deploy, I'm trying to deploy the simple function that comes with firebase init (hello world)

Comment: then I suggest in this case that you [contact support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases) or open a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/new?component=187195&template=802601) if you don't have a support package